# Angular 2 - Seed vs CLI

Tags: angular

I would like to start a new Angular 2 Project.

I found [angular2-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed) and [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) for starting a new project, but am wondering which one to use and what are the pros and cons to them?

Comment: A quick google search seems to return plenty of discussion on this already.

Comment: Unfortunately most of them are outdated. It seems that CLI has changed and gain more power in the last months. Therefore this is a new Question with the current implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are two separate things, angular-cli is a cli tool for generating and serving Angular 2 apps, where as angular2-seed does not handle serving of the app and is just a simple starter project with pre-created components for Angular 2.

So there is no pros or cons to either, it is just down to your requirements. If you want a way to serve the application with other useful commands, use the CLI.

If you are using another way of serving the Angular 2 app, then use angular2-seed.